# Say Email sent but nothing is recieved when sent email using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have used this  several ways but can't seem to get it working. I am running it on live server.

I am using bigrock hosting and as per their document it says just use "localhost" as smtp host. [Link](http://manage.bigrock.in/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq1311.html)

It says email sent but I get nothing..

```
public function index() {
    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'localhost',
        'smtp_port' => '587',
// Other way it say Email sent
        //'smtp_host' => 'ssl://localhost',
        //'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'support@abc.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'sdfsfsdfsd'
    );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('support@abc.com', 'ABC');
        $this->email->to('abc@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Test');
        $this->email->message('Success');
    if ($this->email->send()) {
            echo 'Email Sent';
        } else {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:  $this->email->to('abc@gmail'); make it 'abc@gmail.com' and make sure it is existing..If it still doesn't work, try a legit email from inside you email->from.

Comment: Yes,It did.. Thanks,,